# Java: How to create a general method which returns iterator (columnList) of each line of a big data file

Tags: java, file-io, architecture

This question is more regarding architecture and to enhance my own understanding.

I find myself writing below code over and over whenever I am analyzing tab-delimited data files.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
String line="";
while ( (line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
     List<String> columnList = Splitter.on('\t').splitToList(line);
     //Do something with columns  

}
```

More info on [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

Although nothing is wrong with the above code, I like to know if there is a way to generalize above so that I can put this piece of code in some utility class and keep calling it.

Because the data files would be in giga bytes, I don't want to use  `Files.readLines()`, I still want to use one line at a time and process that line before moving to the next line.

**Question:**

So, is there a way to create something `getFileLineColumnListIterator(String fileName,String delimiter)` and I can simply issue `.next()` on that iterator to get next line's `columnList`, while still preserving the original order of lines?

Hopefully, my question is not drifting towards functional programming paradigm.

**Extra credit** if you could answer how to specify encoding while reading the file as above.

P.S. Please feel free to suggest a better headline for this question, this is the best I could come up.

Comment: Just implement the `Iterator<T>` interface.

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more explicit on how to implement `Iterator<T>` to achieve what I mentioned in the question, hopefully you fully understood my question.

Comment: Since you're already using Guava, why don't you define a LineProcessor and use the [CharStreams.readLines()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#readLines%28java.lang.Readable,%20com.google.common.io.LineProcessor%29) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify encoding you need to use an `InputStreamReader`:

```
try (final BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(myFile), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))) {
}
```

To avoid rewriting the code every time use a library such as OpenCSV - do not reinvent the wheel. For example your code does not cope with escaped delimiters or data wrapped in quotes.

With [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) you can do something like this:

```
try (final CSVReader reader = 
    new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(myFile), Charset.forName("UTF-8")), '\t')) {
    String[] line;
    while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {

    }
}
```

If you really want to do this yourself ignoring the warnings above and assuming you are using Guava you can do something like this:

```
public final class TsvProcessor extends AbstractIterator<List<String>> {

    private final Splitter splitter = Splitter.on('\t');
    private final Scanner s;

    public TsvProcessor(final File file, final String charset) throws FileNotFoundException {
        s = new Scanner(file, charset);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> computeNext() {
        if (!s.hasNext()) {
            s.close();
            return endOfData();
        }
        return splitter.splitToList(s.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Usage being:

```
final Iterator<List<String>> lines = new TsvProcessor(myFile, "UTF-8");
while(lines.hasNext()) {

}
```

Note, in Java 8 you can use the new `Stream` API:

```
final Splitter s = Splitter.on('\t');
Files.lines(myFile.toPath()).map(x -> s.splitToList(x)).forEach(new Consumer<List<String>>() {

    @Override
    public void accept(final List<String> t) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

As @JBNizet suggests you could also use the streaming method of `Files.readLines` that takes a `LineProcessor`:

```
Files.readLines(myFile, Charsets.UTF_8, new LineProcessor<T>() {

    @Override
    public boolean processLine(final String line) throws IOException {
        //process line
    }

    @Override
    public T getResult() {
        //return result
    }
});
```

You can implement your own `LineProcessor` and re-use it. Encapsulate the splitting behaviour into that impl.

From the JavaDoc:

> Streams lines from a File, stopping when our callback returns false,
>   or we have read all of the lines.

Comment: I think the OP in particular wanted to prevent the effects of readAll(), namely filling up memory.

Comment: @Harald changed the code to the use streaming API of OpenCSV.

Comment: @Boris As per my data (which are numbers), I am not too concerned about escaped delimiter. I am concerned about speed when using heavy weight openCSV. In future if my data will have possibility of 'data wrapped in quotes' I will certainly use openCSV.

Comment: @Watt OpenCSV is not heavyweight, it's a fairly light wrapper around a `Reader`. My last alternative should work for you in any case - you are using Guava anyway.

Comment: +1 @BoristheSpider for all the good information, I very much like java 8 way of doing it. I am glad, I posted this question. I will test it out and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about the LineIterator from apache.commons.io
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html

It does exactly what the name suggests and reads a line only when requested.

Comment: +1 Thanks, good to know that it doesn't read all the lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `Iterator` interface directly, and you could use an [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) like this (for your encoding) -

```
String charSet = "UTF-8";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new java.io.InputStreamReader(
        new java.io.FileInputStream(filename), charSet
    )
);
```